# Stanford NLP. The Solution to Draw Graphical Tree

Tags: stanford-nlp

I have a tree. I want to draw it into form(graphical). After that, it can extend to add, delete node, edit pos tag of tree on this graphic. can give me some ideas to start with this issue. sorry for bad english.
example tree:

```
 (ROOT
      (S (NP (NNP John))
        (VP (VBZ loves)
        (NP (NNP Mary)))
        (. .)))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can take a look at [PennTreeReader](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/PennTreeReader.java) in CoreNLP for code to read the string form of a tree into a `Tree` object. Beyond that, the design of the visualization is up to you. A good place to start might be D3; there's even a [CoreNLP Parse Tree demo](http://nlpviz.bpodgursky.com/home).

Comment: I already have Tree object Gabor, now i want to draw it into form. PennTreeReader is not necessary. I looking for a away using Tree object to get node or something can draw tree faster instead of handle String to get node and pos tag

Comment: are you have ever known edu.stanford.nlp.parser.ui? Gabor

Comment: It seems the project has been taken down. There are other examples around though; e.g., https://github.com/arne-cl/d3-dependency-parse-tree